# Showing a divisor is effective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On $\mathbb{P}^n$, consider the prime divisor $C=Z(x_0)$.  Let $f \in k[D(x_0)]$ be degree $d$.  I want to show that the divisor $(f)+\nu_C(f)C$ is effective.  Now, $f=g/x_0^d$ with $g \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ having degree $d$.  Hence, $\nu_C(f)=\nu_C(g)-d\nu_C(x_0)=-d$ because $g$ does not vanish along $C$.  Then the divisor of $f$ should be $(f)=(g)-d(x_0)=(g)-dC$, so $(f)+\nu_C(f)C=(g)-2dC$.  So how can this be effective?  The divisor $(g)$ is effective, but it has no zeros along $C$, so it would seem that this is not the case.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $f$ has degree $d$ but it's $f=g/x^d_0$, where $g$ has degree $d$, is that possible? I'm not familiar with the notation, what do you mean by $k[D(x_0)]$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $f \in k[x_1/x_0,\ldots,x_n/x_0]$ is homogeneous of degree $d$.

Comment: yes, I would say that the divisor $(f)+\nu_C(f)C$ is not effective in general, unless $d=0$ which is probably not what you're after. What is effective is the divisor $(f)-\nu_C(f)C=(g)$.